# Angular Interceptor With Subscribe Not WorkingProperly

Tags: angular, angular9

Hi I have created an interceptor to refresh the token if token expires. Everything is fine except that when token expires before all the interceptor subscribe method gets executed the calling function throws an error.

```
this._customerService.getCustomers(this._customerSearchComp).subscribe(
  (data:any) => {
    
    }
  },
  (error) => {
    this.loader = false;  
    console.log("Inside error while retrieving customer");    
    this.notifyService.openSnackBar('error Thrown' + error, 'snackbar-warning');//this error is thrown before the interceptor subscribe method works
  }
```

And Here is my interceptor.

```
return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
  }
}, async (err: any) => {
  if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
   if (err.status === 401) {
      debugger;
      let token = this._tokenService.getAuthToken();
      let refreshToken=this._tokenService.getRefreshToken(); 


      return this._authenticationService
        .refreshToken({
          token: token,
          refreshToken: refreshToken,
        })
        .subscribe(
          (data: any) => {
            debugger;
            console.log("Token Refreshed");
            this._tokenService.setToken(data.token);
            this._tokenService.setRefreshToken(data.refreshToken);
             this._tokenService.setRefreshToken(data.refreshToken);
            request = request.clone({
              headers: request.headers.set(
                'Authorization',
                'Bearer ' + data.token
              ),
            });

            return next.handle(request);
          },
          (error) => {
            this.dialogRef.closeAll();
            this.notifyService.isTokenExpired=true;
            this._router.navigate(['/']);
          }
        );
      
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: You have refreshed the token but are not using the new token. So use the new token in your request object before calling return next.handle(request).

Comment: @Md.MustafizurRahman, Thanks for your reply. I have set the token inside the subscribe method:
this._tokenService.setToken(data.token);

this._tokenService.setRefreshToken(data.refreshToken);

Comment: @Md.MustafizurRahman Not working even after cloning the request. can you please help.

Comment: Gautam you can follow this article https://angular-academy.com/angular-jwt

Comment: Have you tried to use `concatMap` instead of subscribe?

Comment: @yurzui No i haven't tried. But will subscibe not work?

Comment: +1 for not using subscribe in an interceptor ever. Also +1 for the angular-academy article. Just to be more constructive, here's a pointer: whatever you do in `next.handle(request).do()`, so in the `do` of the observable, will be done _in parallel_ to the external subscribers (ie. the parts which did the rest call). Start with a `pipe` and use operators instead of `do` to manipulate the events _before_ the external subscribers. Interesting question though.